Does an increase in caster level change the effects of an ongoing spell?
Essentially the title. If I cast a spell that has a set parameter based on caster level, and during the duration of the spell my caster level goes up, does this increase said parameter? For example, say I had the spell Greater Magic Weapon active, at CL 7, giving a +1 bonus. If I was a witch with the Coven hex and another witch with the Coven hex used Aid Another on me to increase my caster level, would the Greater Magic Weapon change to a +2 bonus for the duration of the CL increase? Any specific ruling on why this would/wouldn't work would be appreciated. Thanks.

The parameters are set when the spell comes into effect
This is in the rules on magic, under magic basics:

You make all pertinent decisions about a spell (range, target, area, effect, version, and so forth) when the spell comes into effect.

So the parameters of the spell are set at the point in time when the spell comes into effect. That is a specific point in time, not the entire duration of the spell. They are not set during the duration and there is nothing in the general rules for spellcasting that would indicate they change later on (unless spell specifically tells you that you can change it later, as specific rules always overrule the general rule).
In your example, the bonus of the Greater Magic Weapon effect is set when the spell comes into effect, with a +1 bonus. It is set then and only then, and will not change, if the caster level of the witch changes later on, for whatever reason, while the spell is still ongoing, wether it increases or decreases.
As another example, imagine that you cast an Arcane Lock as young wizard at level 3. Your caster level for it is set when the spell comes into effect. The lock does not get harder to dispel later on, just because your wizard has become a level 20 archmage, nor does it go away when your wizard dies (and thus has no caster level any more). It just sticks around with the parameters set at the time it came into effect. If your archmage wizard casts another Arcane Lock later on, that one will be a lot harder to dispel, than the one you did when you were younger and comparatively inexperienced.
